# Unable to use attributes in inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, tweepy

When creating an object of this type:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret, a):
        StreamListener.__init__(self)
        self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        self.stream = Stream(self.auth, self)
        self.stream.filter(track=tweet_filter.strip().split())
        self.a = 2

        print access_token

    def on_data(self, data):
        data_decoded = json.loads(data)
        body = data_decoded['text'].encode('utf-8')
        print self.a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse input arguments

    t_listener = listener(consumer_key=params["consumer_key"],
                          consumer_secret=params["consumer_secret"],
                          access_token=params["access_token"],                                  access_token_secret=params["access_token_secret"],
                          a=3)
```

I don't see access_token printed out, and I also get the error message

> 'listener' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. How are you creating a `listener` object? How are you calling `on_data`?

Comment: What is `tweet_listener` here?

Comment: Well, not really. What is `tweet_listener` - is that supposed to be `listener`? And you still haven't shown where you're calling `on_data`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I suspect `StreamListener` does this. OP, please show us what project you are using so we can confirm. No, twitter4j can't be it, because that's a Java library.

Comment: Is this [tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html) perhaps?

Comment: I'd highly recommend setting `self.a` **before** calling all the other stuff like `StreamListener.__init__` if it is going to be calling `on_data`.

Comment: If this *is* tweepy, read the tutorial more carefully, and follow their advice to first read the [authentication tutorial](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.4.0/auth_tutorial.html#auth-tutorial). You'd create a `tweepy.OAuthHandler()`, and pass the that in to a `tweepy.API()` object. You then create a `tweepy.Stream()` object with the API auth object and your listener. There is no need for the listener to care about authentication.

Comment: yes, but why is it messing things up?

Comment: @Bob: because `self.stream.filter()` never returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.stream.filter()` never returns. It is the point at which the Tweepy API calls out to Twitter, and in a loop receives the twitter stream for your listener to handle. You can't create the stream inside the listener initialiser, as the stream needs the listener to be fully created before it can start.

Simply don't put `Stream()` handling in the listener. Handle that *separately* and pass in your `StreamListener()` instance *outside* of the `__init__` method.

If your listener must have access to the API, just pass it in; the original [`StreamListener.__init__()` method](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/streaming.py#L30) accepts an `api` argument:

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import API
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

class listener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None, a=None):
        StreamListener.__init__(self, api=api)
        self.a = a

    def on_data(self, data):
        data_decoded = json.loads(data)
        body = data_decoded['text'].encode('utf-8')
        print self.a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # parse input arguments
    auth = OAuthHandler(params["consumer_key"], params["consumer_secret"],)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token=params["access_token"], params["access_token_secret"])
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    listener = listener(api, 3)
    stream = Stream(self.auth, listener)
    stream.filter(track=tweet_filter.strip().split())
```